# 4D Convolutional Network

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Does anyone know if there is a generalization of convolutional network that works with 4D input tensors rather than 3D. Generally, as I understand it, convolutional network filters accept a certain span of x,y coordinates per filter and the entire depth of that span as well. I have an additional dimension that would need to be required within the filters for the input to make any sense.

Is it possible to use a traditional convolutional network for this or is there an abstraction that works for n-dimensional data?

Comment: I haven't yet seen any papers that directly mention multidimensional convolutionals, but it may be trivial to implement - depending on what software package you're using, of course. I use T-SQL whenever possible, in which one can easily model any number of dimensions and use some simple GROUP BY clauses etc. to select, update, insert into a neural net with layers of arbitrary size. Expanding to 4D & higher dimensions is really a non-issue there. I can't comment on what's available in packages like  R or Matlab or recent versions of Weka, but I suspect it'd be harder to implement in those.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow defines the convolution in N dimensions and the transposed, RELU layer is dimension independent, the only problem you will have is with the pooling layers that you will have to implement on your own (feel free to submit them later to tf contributions). So I guess your problem is perfectly addressable with TF